# Failed to bind data sent from a controller to view angular.js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

my app is currently only 3 small parts a service which make `http` call to `.json` file a controller that recive data from the service and send it to a view.
When i hard code the data in my service it was working well.

When i replaced the hard coded data to `.json` file it stop working however i logged it in the controller and made sure the data querying correctly from the `.json` file.

here is the simple controller:

```
(function (){
    'user strict';
    angular.module('myApp').controller('itemsCtrl',['$state','myappApi', itemsCtrl]);
    //constructor function
    function itemsCtrl($state, myappApi){
        var vm = this;

        myappApi.getItems(function(data){
            vm.items = data;
        });
        //vm.items = data;

        vm.selectItem = function(id){
            myappApi.setItemId(id);
            $state.go("app.item-detail");

        }
    };
})();
```

The Template code:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="itemsCtrl as vm">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
        <div class="list">
            <a class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="item in vm.items" ng-click="vm.selectItem(item.id)">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col item-thumbnail-left">
                        <img ng-src="vas-images/{{item.name}}.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-center">
                        <h3 class="blue-font">{{item.name}}</h3>
                        <p>{{item.desc}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-center">
                        <h4 class="blue-font-alt">Price:{{item.price}}$</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The service code:

```
(function (){
    'user strict';
    angular.module('myApp').factory('myappApi',['$http', myappApi]);

    function myappApi($http){

        //function to get all the items.
        function getItems(callback){
            $http.get("app/items/data.json")
            .success(function(data){
                callback(data);
            });
        }

        //function to set the item ID.
        function setItemId(itemId){
            currentItemId = itemId;
        }

        return{
            getItems: getItems,
            setItemId: setItemId
        };
    };
})();
```

The `.json` file:

```
{
    "items" : [
    {"id":1005, "name":"item-one", "desc":"some text here and there", "price":100},
    {"id":1006, "name":"item-two", "desc":"some text here and there", "price":500},
    {"id":1007, "name":"item-three", "desc":"some text here and there", "price":600},
    {"id":1008, "name":"item-four", "desc":"some text here and there", "price":50},
    {"id":1009, "name":"item-five", "desc":"some text here and there", "price":20},
    {"id":1010, "name":"item-six", "desc":"some text here and there", "price":660}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Updated the plunker, still working fine...

Comment: i did update the code according to your answer, i still getting the data in the console like before but, what i noticed that before my list get only one blank item, now after updating the code according to yours i have 5 blank items blank i mean no name no desc nothing just list item

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention that i also update my template with this code of yours {{ vm.items | json }} and i got all the data in format of json. just no data in my list.

Comment: Make a plunker out of it and then we'll see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's something wrong with your data because the following works just fine with backing JSON file.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="itemsCtrl as vm">
  {{ vm.items | json }}
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('itemsCtrl', function(myappApi){
  var vm = this;
  myappApi.getItems(function(response){
    vm.items = response.data;
  });
});

myApp.factory('myappApi', function myappApi($http){
  return {
    getItems: function(callback){
      $http.get('data.json').then(callback).catch(callback);
    }  
  };
});
```

**JSON**

```
[{
  "name": "name",
  "desc": "desc",
  "price": 100
}]
```

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/NY2Un3

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, you should inject `$scope` into your controller. Some previous versions of angular do let you use `this` and `$scope` interchangeably, so maybe saying `var vm = this` and assigning to `vm` will work in some versions of angular, but I would suggest setting up your controller like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('itemsCtrl',['$scope', '$state','myappApi', itemsCtrl]);
//constructor function
function itemsCtrl($scope, $state, myappApi){
    myappApi.getItems(function(data){
        $scope.items = data;
    });

    $scope.selectItem = function(id){
        myappApi.setItemId(id);
        $state.go("app.item-detail");
    }
};
```

But even if, in your version of angular, `this` is a viable substitute for `$scope`, you can't reference the scope itself from the template - only properties *on the scope*. So you need to change this line:

```
<a class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="item in vm.items" ng-click="vm.selectItem(item.id)">
```

to

```
<a class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="selectItem(item.id)">
            <div class="row">
```

i.e. `item in items` instead of `item in vm.items` and `selectItem(item.id)` instead of `vm.selectItem(item.id)`. Since `vm` is not a property on scope, it's not accessible in the template.

(And incidentally, you should replace `vm.whatever` throughout the template. I didn't look closely at the rest.)

--EDIT--

I apologize. I did not notice your `ng-controller="itemsCtrl as vm"` at the top. So this may not be the answer to your problem after all. I'm going to leave this answer here for now, however, since at least one person has already found it useful.

I never use the "controller as" feature, but I wonder if maybe you shouldn't be doing `var vm = this`. It doesn't seem like there should be a variable scoping issue, but I guess I would be wary of naming the variable the same thing in both places.

Did you try adding a `.error` handler to your `$http` call? Maybe that will tell you if something is going wrong (e.g. can't find the file).

Comment: Hello, i did had .erro and there is no error occured, also am logging the data am getting from the .json correctly

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if the answer is silly but i just updated my `.json` file to

```
[
{"id":1005, "name":"item-one", "desc":"some text here and there", "price":100},
{"id":1006, "name":"item-two", "desc":"some text here and there", "price":500},
{"id":1007, "name":"item-three", "desc":"some text here and there", "price":600},
{"id":1008, "name":"item-four", "desc":"some text here and there", "price":50},
{"id":1009, "name":"item-five", "desc":"some text here and there", "price":20},
{"id":1010, "name":"item-six", "desc":"some text here and there", "price":660}
]
```